# Issue with video drivers on Xubuntu 17.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, nouveau

I was running Xubuntu 16.10 with no issue, then I upgraded to 17.04 and suddenly was having issues with booting and shutdown.  I did a clean build of 17.04, and it was working fine, until I switched from the Nvidia driver to the Nouveau driver.  When I did that, I saw the same issues with starting up and shutting down again, so obviously it's that driver.  But when I run the Nvidia driver, I have issues with video in VLC.  Fast forward/rewind is very slow, and trying to play a video file at anything other than 1X doesn't work at all.  It works fine with the Nouveau driver, and it's not a hardware issue, I've got plenty of power, this is what I'm running: https://us.msi.com/Laptop/GE62-Apache-GTX-965M.html#hero-overview

Anyone seen issues like this?

EDIT: Output of *lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'*

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HD Graphics 530
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.